# webview inside tabview getting exception

Tags: android, android-webview

In my app I am using web-view inside tab-view.In my app i used 5 tabs.In my app one activity having connect button available in side tabs.whenever connect button clicked web-view opened inside tabs fine.In that web-view Facebook URL is available.whenever entered username and password and clicked getting the following exception.

And I am using the following code in web-view activity:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.facebook);
    wvFacebook=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wvFacebook.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    wvFacebook.loadUrl(http://facebook.com);
    }
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{            
    pdHandler pdHandler;
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
              {
               Log.e("status....","WebViewClient");
//             view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
               view.loadUrl(url);

                  return true;
              }   
       }
}
```

This exception getting in device version 4.2(jelly bean)

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add
windowtokenandroid.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@41e841a0 is not valid;    is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.onSavePassword(WebViewClassic.java:1853)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:497)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But bellow 4.2 devices whenever connect button clicked Facebook login page opened inside tab-view well.but username and password edit-boxes not responding.please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: are you trying to show any sort of alert dialog by yourself?

Comment: yes i tried.again same problem

Comment: no. I mean can you add more relevant code? Are you getting the exception bcoz of the webview or an alert dialog from the webview?

Comment: inside webview activity i used above code only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something other than Facebook ? maybe its api stuff problem

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:
```

Maybe this answer will help you

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12086960/1932105)