# Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application from Service

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have read many questions like this but none of them seemed to address my problem.

The problem lies with:

```
 AlertScreen ad = new AlertScreen(SensorListenerService.this);
```

in my Service class:

```
public class SensorListener extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    startForeground(Process.myPid(), new Notification());

    AlertScreen ad = new AlertScreen(SensorListener.this); //problem
    ad.show();
    
    return START_STICKY;
}
...
```

It calls my AlertScreen class:

```
public class AlertScreen extends AlertDialog {

public AlertScreen(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
...
```

What LogCat has to say:

[image: LocCat]

Could anyone shed some light on the problem?

Comment: try this `AlertScreen ad = new AlertScreen(this);` on `onCreate()` of your service.

Comment: @SimplePlan Nope, same story.

Comment: Any success with my answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot show Dialogs from a Service context.

I suggest you to open an Activity that actually shows the dialog, or take a look at this answer to learn how to show system alerts.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/19269931/1725088