# Why do I get token null is not valid error in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I hope to open a dialog box, the Code A works well.  In order to make the code universally, I place the function promptBuyWhenExpired into Utility.kt, then I invoke the function in onCreate() just like Code B, but I get the following error information, what wrong do I make ?

**Error Information**

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.dodata.mirror/ui.UIMain}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:765)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:92)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:330)
        at utility.UtilityKt.promptBuyWhenExpired(Utility.kt:106)
        at ui.UIMain.onCreate(UIMain.kt:70)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
```

**Code A**

```
class UIMain : AppCompatActivity() { 
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main)

        promptBuyWhenExpired()

    }

    private fun promptBuyWhenExpired() {
        if (IsExpired(applicationContext) ) {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.ExpiredTitle))
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.ExpiredWarning))
            builder.setCancelable(false)
            builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.BtnYes)) { dialog, which ->
                finish()
            }
            builder.create().show()
        }
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class UIMain : AppCompatActivity() { 
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main)

        Utility.promptBuyWhenExpired(this)
    }

}




Utility.kt
public fun promptBuyWhenExpired(mActivity: Activity) {
    var mContent= mActivity.applicationContext
    if (IsExpired(mContent) ) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mContent)
        builder.setMessage(mContent.getString(R.string.ExpiredTitle))
        builder.setTitle(mContent.getString(R.string.ExpiredWarning))
        builder.setCancelable(false)
        builder.setPositiveButton(mContent.getString(R.string.BtnYes)) { dialog, which ->
            mActivity.finish()
        }
        builder.create().show()
    }
}
```

**Modified in Code B**

The following code can work, but I don't know if the code can work well in all mobile phone.

```
//promptBuyWhenExpired(this@UImain) is Ok
//promptBuyWhenExpired(this) is Ok too.
public fun promptBuyWhenExpired(mActivity: Activity) {
    var mContent= mActivity.applicationContext
    if (IsExpired(mContent) ) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)  //The paramter is mActivity
        builder.setMessage(mContent.getString(R.string.ExpiredTitle))
        builder.setTitle(mContent.getString(R.string.ExpiredWarning))
        builder.setCancelable(false)
        builder.setPositiveButton(mContent.getString(R.string.BtnYes)) { dialog, which ->
            mActivity.finish()
        }
        builder.create().show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PopupWindow $BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782250/popupwindow-badtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-valid)

Comment: replace mContent with mActivity in AlertDialog.Builder(mContent)

Comment: check for `if (!isFinishing && !isDestroyed)` for your `activity` inside your `promptBuyWhenExpired()`.

Comment: In Utility: `val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mContent)` here you are using application context not activity context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to
>   add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Read [**`This Expression`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) .

**DO**

This Step for **Code B**

```
 Utility.promptBuyWhenExpired(this@UIMain)
```

Then

```
public fun promptBuyWhenExpired(mActivity: Activity) {
       if (IsExpired(mActivity) ) {
```

You should pass **`this@CurrentActivityName`** instead of **`this`**.

**NOTE**

```
builder.setPositiveButton(mContent.getString(R.string.BtnYes)) { dialog, which ->

            val handler = Handler()
            handler.postDelayed({  mActivity.finish() }, 300)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! but I still the same error when I use Utility.promptBuyWhenExpired(this@UIMain)

Comment: Are there some problem with the function public fun promptBuyWhenExpired(mActivity: Activity) {...} in Code B ?

Comment: Is `var mContent= mActivity.applicationContext` right in my Code B?

Comment: @HelloCW comment `var mContent= mActivity.applicationContext`

Comment: @HelloCW  use `val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@UIMain)`

Comment: Thanks!   'mActivity.finish()' will cause error by your code because `public fun promptBuyWhenExpired(mActivity: Context) {...}` in Code B

Comment: @HelloCW add `dialog.dismiss()` before `mActivity.finish()`

Comment: I hope to close UImain instead of dialog

Comment: and more ,you can't invoke `mActivity.finish()` because mActivity is Context by your code `public fun promptBuyWhenExpired(mActivity: Context)...`

Comment: A Context havn't finish() function

Comment: @HelloCW good. For test case comment `mActivity.finish()` and let me inform

Comment: Thanks! but I need to invoke finish() to close UIMain

Comment: @HelloCW  Add 300 ms delay time to avoid exception

Comment: Thanks! Would you please see my modified question? My modified code can work,   but I don't know if the code can work well in all mobile phone.

Comment: In modified code, I can pass parameter either `this` or `this@UIMain`, why? Thanks!

Comment: @HelloCW Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933206/android-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-exception