# getting error related to activity is not running in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-context, customdialog

I am creating a project with one activity and 3 fragments on it with bottom navigation. in onAttach() function i get the context and work with it app was working properly but suddenly i got error mention below on opennig the custom dialogue on research i came to know it came due to activity is finished but how is that possible that activity is finished the fragment is running on that activity also context is not null getContext() is also returning context properly

to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

the only solution i found is to check for activity if its running i will show the dialogue other wise not

Dialog which is not opening is

```
MyAlertDialogue.getInstance(mContext)
        .setLayout(R.layout.dialogue_notify)
        .showTitle("Info")
        .showPositiveButton("Ok")
        .showMessage("Task Done!")
        .show();
```

That's What i  am getting

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:953)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:329)
        at co.xeontechnologies.slapapp.utils.MyAlertDialogue.show(MyAlertDialogue.java:160)
        at co.xeontechnologies.slapapp.fragments.HomeFragment.btn_inzo(HomeFragment.java:234)
        at co.xeontechnologies.slapapp.fragments.HomeFragment_ViewBinding$1.doClick(HomeFragment_ViewBinding.java:45)
        at 

 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 0):

set `getContext()`

```
 MyAlertDialogue.getInstance(getContext())
            .setLayout(R.layout.dialogue_notify)
            .showTitle("Info")
            .showPositiveButton("Ok")
            .showMessage("Task Done!")
            .show();
```

or this may be helpfull [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933206/android-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-exception](http://Android%20'Unable%20to%20add%20window%20%E2%80%94%20token%20null%20is%20not%20for%20an%20application'%20exception)

Comment: Hello yuvrajsinh i have already tried this solution but no success