# Create datePicker inside adapter in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, datepicker, adapter, dynamic-forms

I have a recyclerView adapter. Inside that there is dynamic form. The form is created in respect to the type which is sent from server. It is working in the case of strings but when there is Case "date" an error occur.
The error is

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

The code can be seen below;

```
holder.et.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                SimpleDateFormat fr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                holder.et.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

The above error is in the line

```
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: It's because of your _context_. `context` stands for what ?

Comment: looks like `context` you are using is not a valid one.

Comment: Ya context was not valid one. I had sent getApplicationContext(). and i just found we cannot sent like that. We have to send like ActivityName.this. Thanks for your help. The problem is solved

Comment: Yes. That's true. You needed to use _ActivityName.this_ instead of _getApplicationContext()_

Comment: yes. Thanks for help @Piyush

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your context. Please use Activity.this or pass the activity context to your adapter. Think your Issue will get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a 3 hour to figure it out and turns out this is very simple method.
All you need to know when you used any dialog in adapter,getContext(),context or activity won't work sometime.

Here is the trick I used
     `v.getRootView().getContext()`
where v is the view object you are referencing.
Eg.

```
holder.mDateText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new DatePickerDialog(v.getRootView().getContext(), date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });
```

Also refer here..
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367771/displaying-alertdialog-inside-a-custom-listadapter-class)

Comment: How is that possible we are adding only one datepickerdialog, you might be using two dialog or two function.